# Implementing Elastic search on EMC Documentum stored file content

Tags: java, c#, elasticsearch, documentum

Hi I am trying to implement the searching on the content of EMC documentum documents(majorly word/pdf). This would be two step.
1) Downloading the document content from documentum repository. Using DFS and REST to implement this.
2) Applying elastic search on the downloaded content. Can you tell me how can i achieve this?

Any other approach to solve this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Documentum itself provides search on the content of the documents on the basis of meta-data by using the key-words.So by adding most of the meta-data could solve your problem. You could read the files and set the high frequency key-words as meta-data for those files and leave the indexing to documentum.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Documentum xPlore? Its a plataform Lucene-based, as ElasticSearch, and provide the most of features that a fulltext engine have. This implementation work without DFS and REST, by using Content Server resources. But you can use DFS or Rest to consume the specific fulltext searches.